# Strange javascript & web server requests behaviour, hosting a fresh OpenCart installation

Tags: javascript, caching, opencart

I am not sure if this is a client or a server problem, but this is 2nd time I meet this kind of problem in this specific server that I am using for the first time. Never met it before.

My OpenCart website does not load all the images until I customly select "Load Image" from my browser. Also theme objects alignment have problems.

Sometimes, and this is the most strange thing I met, when I select from my browser (chrome) "Open Link in a new tab" to and unloaded image, I get javascript code instead of an image preview. Javascript code seems also to misbehaviour, ie does not open drop down menus in mouse click.

What kind of problem is that? I disabled all my extensions in Chrome and tested also the website in FireFox. Same strange behaviour. I suspect server's cache problems. Any ideas to solve it?

[image]

[image]

Also in Admin page, I get instantly the error "Invalid token session. Please login again" without entering any credentials.

[image]

Comment: Going just off of the picture, that looks like a server problem.  It is returning javascript when you requested a png.  So either some routing stuff is messed up, or someone actually saved a javascript file as a png file

Comment: @Taplar No, for sure there is no way I have saved a png file as *.js. How to ask customer support to help? The 1st time I met this problem, they solved it but they told me that it never had a problem at all.

Comment: If you are paying for customer support, then this is not a S.O. question.  You need to be using the service you paid for.